# How to make the border consistent in bootstrap's input-group while appending an image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a search box in a navbar and I get this effect:

[image: search box with bad border]

So my problem is that I can't manage to make the border consistent - I want the icon to have the same border as the "Search..." box with no border in between them.

The code for it looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group" style="width: 10rem;">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="button-addon5" class="form-control">
<div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="button-addon5" type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: White;">
        <svg class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="color: rgb(230,0,0);">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 011.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 100-11 5.5 5.5 0 000 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 11-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0113 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

The closest I got to solving it is by looking up bootstrap's css and copying the border properties to the button element and then setting the border-left to none, but then there were problems with rounder corners being visible despite no left border. Even if it would be possible to delete just left corners, I feel like there must be a better way... :/

Comment: why not just add right padding to your input and then absolutely position the button on top 
 of the input

Comment: @Pete's suggestion is nice, you could also define a border radius like that: `border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0` where 10px is the value you want. This will remove the border radius on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the border utils on the button...

```
   <div class="input-group" style="width: 10rem;">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="button-addon5" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button id="button-addon5" type="submit" class="btn border-left-0 border" style="background-color: White;">
                <svg class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="color: rgb(230,0,0);">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 011.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 010-1.415z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 100-11 5.5 5.5 0 000 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 11-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0113 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/wLgphISgj2